# jquery ready method

Tags: jquery, dom, document-ready

The following snippet of jquery says wait until the document is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
     // my code
});
```

what are other objects that can be passed to `$()` in place of document parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

according to the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

*The .ready() method can only be called on a jQuery object **matching the current document***

But my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a6Lt6/1/) shows that it's not true!!!

**HTML:**

```
<div id="gdoron">
    <input value='aaa' />
</div>​
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#gdoron').ready(function() {
    alert($('#gdoron').html()); // alerts: "<input value='aaa' />"
});​

alert($('#gdoron').html()); // alerts: "null"
```

Maybe what the docs meant is that `this` inside the handler will be `document` object and not the element corresponding to the selector?(which is true...)

The code that fire the readyList handlers:

```
readyList.fireWith( document, [ jQuery ] );
```

Anyway why wouldn't you use the `document` object? this is the only DOM object that will always be defined, not like `body` etc'.

---

All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:

- `$(document).ready(handler)`
- `$().ready(handler)` (this is not recommended)
- `$(handler)`

Comment: but if you console.log on that this is in your fiddle code you will get document as a reference not #gdoron so you cant use it for example: `$(this).addClass("gdoron")`

Comment: **+1** maybe that is what the docs meant...? Added it to my answer. thanks!

Comment: on line 435(jQuery 1.7.1): `readyList.fireWith( document, [ jQuery ] );` there it is ;) (if you want to add that also?)

Answer (score 1):

jQuerys documentation on [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) says:

> The .ready() method can only be called on a jQuery object matching the current document, so the selector can be omitted.

Most people are using:

```
$(function(){});
```

its shorter and less confusing ;)

Answer (score 1):

The .ready() method can only be called on a jQuery object matching the current document